# how to set text in textView?

Tags: android, textview

How do I set the text in TextView dynamically?

Layout file:

```
<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap content"
    android:layout_height="wrap content"/>
```

Code:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
```

How to set the text now?

Comment: From the next time... for syntax related querries... go to android doc... [here.](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setText(java.lang.CharSequence, android.widget.TextView.BufferType)

Comment: google first before posting question on SO

Comment: Beofre Posting Please search in google

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set the text in xml file by:

```
android:text="some text"
```

or in code by following

```
textView.setText("some text");
```

Answer (score 3):

`textView.setText(R.string.yourString)` or `textView.setText("your string");`

Answer (score 1):

PLease do some google before asking those kind of questions. Anyway:

```
textview.setText("Text");
```

Answer (score 0):

textView.setText("text_which you want to enter");

or textView.setText("Your Text");

you can use string also 
as R.String.stringname you can add this into values which is in res.

[You can get more easy android tutorial at here](http://www.androidviews.net/home/)